# ECB not showing "hidden" (.*) directories in file browser window

Tags: emacs

I'm running emacs-23.3 with ecb-2.40 and have noticed that the file browser does not show .* directories.

For example, the .emacs.d folder does not show up on the file browser, even though I can find files inside that folder and then the full path including .emacs.d shows up in the History window.

Has anyone run into this before and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think ecb file browser is just a wrapper for dired.. in which case take a look at your 
'dired-omit-files' variable using 'C-h v'. i have mine set as

```
"^\\.?#\\|^\\.$\\|^\\...+$"
```

which omits temp emacs files, the (pointless) link to current directory, and finally, all files beginning with '.', being mindful to not remove the useful '..' link. so try,

```
M-: (setq dired-omit-files "^\\.?#\\|^\\.$")
```

..and see if that does the trick for you. if so, pop it in yours .emacs (without the M-:)